# laravel if request is username in blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have simple URL /players/USERNAME to view user profile. I want to insert some thing only in user profile page. Cuz user profile got another links.
Example:

```
@if (Request::is('players/{{ $user->slug }}'))
@include('users::stats') 
@endif
```

But dont get anything. Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be something like `@if(Route::is('prayer.show', ['user' => $user->slug]))` where `parayer.show` is the name of your route and `user` is the param

Comment: @Espresso thanks for answer. I do like that: `@if(Route::is('users.show', ['user' => $user->slug]))
@include('users::stats') 
@endif ` still nothing. My route: `ModuleRoute::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'edit', 'update']]);
ModuleRoute::get('players/{slug}', 'UsersController@show');
`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `Request::is` is necessary in your blade view. You should have a route defined in your `web.php` file to capture that pattern meaning you already know the end user is on `players/{username}`.

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/players/{slug}', [
    PlayerController::class, 'show'
])->name('players.show');
```

**PlayerController.php**

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $slug')->firstOrFail();

    return view('players.show', compact('user'));
}
```

**Blade view (players/show.blade.php)**

```
// some stuff

@include('users.stats')

// some other stuff
```

Note that I've named the methods and files based on what you've provided, you'll need to change them to be whatever they are in your project.